# Remove div border element for title space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this effect below:

[image]

How can I get this effect? I want the empty space to adjust to the text. Can anyone give me advice?

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.box__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h2 class="box__title">Box title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you just add background color white to the h2?

Comment: add baground-color white and add maybe same X-paddings to the box__title class or add fieldset > legend Tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`tag.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Box Title</legend>

    <h1>More stuff here!</h1>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. Will accept your answer in 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can add a background color and some left and right padding to your box title

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.box__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h2 class="box__title">Box title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is I will have a texture as a background color, so I cant add just white background. Possible to add "empty" background?

Comment: well then see if the answer from SecretTimes works for you